# Public static ArrayList get- with for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, static, bluej

I'm new to Java and I'm stuck at a point where I'm supposed to complete a method with a static ArrayList; I have to use a for loop. I've tried to ask several people but I simply don't understand what to do.

It looks like this (I'm supposed to complete it)

```
public static ArrayList<Message> getMessagesTo(Person recipient) {
    ArrayList<Message> allMessages = getMessages();
    return allMessages;
}
```

and so far what I've done is this

```
public static ArrayList<Message> getMessagesTo(Person recipient) {
    ArrayList<Message> allMessages = getMessages();
    for(Message message : allMessages) {
        System.out.println(message.getMessageBody());

        if(message.getRecipient().getName().equals(recipient)) {
            getMessagesTo(recipient);


    }
            return allMessages;
```

(BlueJ) then says "missing return statement" but I know that my mistake is in this part:

```
if(message.getRecipient().getName().equals(recipient)) {
                getMessagesTo(recipient);


            }
```

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3788176)

Comment: What do you specifically mean by "a method with a static ArrayList", and what do you have to do with the loop?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a closing `}` in the if statement

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a free tutor service where you drop unclear requirements and we teach the variety of things that might be relevant here.

Comment: @Hermos are you meaning to compare a recipient's *name* to a *recipient*? Should it not be `message.getRecipient().equals(recipient)`, or `message.getRecipient().getName().equals(recipient.getName())`?

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm not sure if I did that one right(I probably didn't) I'm supposed to return all of the messages sent to a recipient (whose name is given as a parameter)

Comment: @GhostCat I'm sorry if it came across that way. I'm new to this and english isn't my first language, I didn't mean to make anything unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to define an `ArrayList`, add elements to it and return it, e.g.:

```
public static ArrayList<Message> getMessagesTo(Person recipient) {
ArrayList<Message> allMessages = getMessages();
ArrayList<Message> messagesToPerson = new ArrayList<Message>();
for(Message message : allMessages) {
    System.out.println(message.getMessageBody());

    if(message.getRecipient().getName().equals(recipient)) {
        messagesToPerson.add(message);
    }
}
return messagesToPerson;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're missing several  Brackets in your Code

```
public static ArrayList<Message> getMessagesTo(Person recipient) {
  ArrayList<Message> allMessages = getMessages();
  for(Message message : allMessages) {
      System.out.println(message.getMessageBody());

      if(message.getRecipient().getName().equals(recipient)) {
          getMessagesTo(recipient);
      }
  }
  return allMessages;
}
```

Comment: why not its `if(message.getRecipient().getName().equals(recipient.getName()))`